# Reading a file into a CharBuffer, then a StringBuilder or StringBuffer seems to leave out on parts of the file. Why?

Tags: java

The following code seems to only write a small part of the File in the StringBuilder - why?

```
    Reader rdr = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(...)));
    StringBuilder buf = new StringBuilder();
    CharBuffer cbuff = CharBuffer.allocate(1024);
    while(rdr.read(cbuff) != -1){
        buf.append(cbuff);
        cbuff.clear();
    }
    rdr.close();
```

Some more information: The file is bigger than the CharBuffer, also i can see from the debugger that the charbuffer is indeed filled as expected. The only part that makes its way to the StringBuilder seems to be from somewhere in the middle of the file. I am using openJDK7.
I wonder why it would show such a behavior and how this can be fixed.

Comment: I am surprised this works without calling `cbuff.flip();` between read() and append()

Comment: You know what? I think you just gave the answer. The last read() only fills part of the Buffer, then the append will append "old" bytes from the end. Could this be how it works?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As Peter Lawrey mentioned, you need to call `cbuff.flip()` between the read and write. It seems that the append will read from the position of the buffer, which is **at the end** if we don't call `cbuff.flip()`. The reason why a part from somewhere in the middle is still written is because in the end, the buffer won't be completely filled, thus some "old" bytes will still be between the position in the buffer and the end of the buffer.

Mystery solved :-)

Answer (score 1):

All those classes have been part of the JDK since 1.0.  I doubt that any of them needs to be fixed.

Your code is a long way for the usual idiom.  Was this intended as a learning exercise, one that's gone awry?  Or did you really want to put this into an application?

Here's how I would expect to see those classes used:

```
public static final String NEWLINE = System.getProperty("line.separator");

public String readContents(File f) throws IOException {
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(1024);
    BufferedReader br = null;
    try {
        br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(f));
        String line;
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            builder.append(line).append(NEWLINE);
        }
    } finally { 
        closeQuietly(br);
    }
    return builder.toString();
}
```

Comment: i think you are right. I wanted to avoid that and ended up with something worse :-P. Still this doesn't answer the question as to **why** this doesn't work.

Comment: This strips new line characters which might not be desirable.

Comment: So add them in.  I'll do it.  I'll agree that this answer doesn't explain your problem, but I'm not sure that I'd want to encourage you to use the code you posted.

Comment: Most the Reader subsystem was added in 1.1, CharBuffers 1.4, and  StringBuilders 1.5.  You're opening salvo of "All of these classes have been part of the JDK since 1.0" is eye grabbing, but entirely false.

Comment: So you think they're all fatally flawed and still need to be fixed?   All in need of a rewrite instead of advising a novice to look at what they've done?  This is needed after three years?